# Starting an executable within the E:\ drive with Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am having a problem starting a .exe file with a batch file.
The program is called "ck.exe" and exists in the E:\ drive as part of the DVD-RW for the PC game "Myst III Exile"
[Myst III Cover Art if you want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rllpS.png)
I want to do this because the game does not have a nice built in way to run the program from the desktop
The folder looks like:

```
Computer >
   DVD RW Drive (E:) Exile DVD >
      ...
      ck.exe
      ...
```

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
REM a batch file that starts Exile or tells you if the disc is in
IF EXIST E: GOTO Start
PAUSE>nul
:Start
CD \
ECHO found the front drive
CD E: 
ECHO found E: drive
E:\ck.exe
ECHO began program
PAUSE>nul
EXIT
```

My OS is Windows 7 and cmd.exe is running with administrator privileges

**NOTE**: This program does not return an error, however the command prompt displays:

```
found the front drive
E:\
found E: drive
began program
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make a directory on e:\ the current directory, change the current drive as well as the directory:

```
cd /d E:\
```

Only `cd E:` is not enough for that.